# Problem connecting to obd-ii via python-obd

Tags: python, obd-ii

I have an orange pi and I have installed python-obd library, it throws an exception when I try to connect or even when I try to scan the ports, apparently it comes from the pyserial library (version 3.4), this is the error it gives:

```
import obd
ports = obd.scan_serial()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/obd/utils.py", line 189, in scan_serial
if try_port(port):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/obd/utils.py", line 161, in try_port
raise e
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/obd/utils.py", line 153, in try_port
s = serial.Serial(portStr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
self.open()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 286, in open
self._update_dtr_state()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 634, in _update_dtr_state
fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCMBIS, TIOCM_DTR_str)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Same error ocurrs with python2.7 and python3. Any idea what might be happening?